# Redirecting to the same page but switched language url, using Nuxt.js and Vue-i18n

Tags: regex, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I am trying to redirect the user through a method when he clicks on specific buttons to change the language of the application. 

These buttons are part of the standard layout of which all the pages of the project are part of so the url can differ based on which `.vue` page the user is on but the buttons are always the same which means that the redirecting has to be dynamic.

For example the url :

```
localhost/about
```

Should be redirected through the method (by pressing the specific button) to :

```
localhost/bg/about
```

In the project the pages are inside a folder `_locale` and imported also from the .vue files outside of this folder as suggested in the Nuxt documentation for localization with Vue-i18n https://nuxtjs.org/examples/i18n/

 The same way are implemented the `nuxt.config.js` , `i18n.js` middleware, `i18n.js` plugin and `index.js` store files.

Since it is a `Nuxt.js` application and not just a `Vue.js` one, just committing the mutation of the store through a page changing the `locale` (the language) doesn't also actually change the language and even if it did ( using `this.$i18n.locale = 'bg'` for example ) it only changes it for the specific page and with the next navigation it uses again the `fallback locale` instead, so I am trying to solve it with redirecting which does use then the correct `.json` file of the language based on the url. I am just trying to find a way for this redirecting to be more dynamic instead of nagigating only back to the `home` page of each language.

If needed the github repo : https://github.com/alexgil1994/logistics-gls

Steps needed :

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Could it be done in some better way? Is there any example of Regex for such a situation? Is there an easier way than Regex?

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long time since I made this question and I had forgotten that I had found a custom workaround so since the time came to implement it again for another project I thought of finally closing the question.

Since I searched again for possible internationalization solutions I found that there are two possible ones (at least) :

**1).** Custom solution using `Nuxt` and `vue-i18n` is to use a method triggered by the user when he/she chooses one of language choices :

```
changeLanguage(locale) {
          // -- Getting the path before starting
          var beforePath = this.$nuxt.$router.history.current.path

          // -- Removing the previous locale from the url
          var result = ''
          result = beforePath.replace( "/bg", "" )
          result = result.replace( "/gr", "" )

          // -- Redirecting to the same page but in the desired language
          if ( locale == 'gr' || locale == 'bg' ) {
            this.$nuxt.$router.replace({ path: '/' + locale + result })
          } else {
            if ( result == '/' ) {
              this.$nuxt.$router.replace({ path: '/' + locale })
            } else {
              this.$nuxt.$router.replace({ path: '/' + locale + result })
            }
          }
      }
```

You can see I am passing in the `locale` argument which is the language code that was choosen and we use the `$nuxt.$router` to get the current path.

**2).** The second solution would be to use `nuxt` and `nuxt-i18n` instead. This way one can use the method `switchLocalePath` as described in the [official documentation](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/basic-usage.html). Though I haven't really tried (I remember I tried it 8 months ago but had some problems, I probably had implemented it the wrong way). Will give it another go soon.

Hopefully this will be of help to someone else

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! He is very helpful

Comment: Glad it helped you :)
In case you instead use Nuxt with `nuxt-i18n` the `switchLocalePath` does work pretty well, I have just tested it for a project. For farther informations about it look into the documentation at [nuxt-i18n documentation](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/).